# Reading from binary after x bytes in C

Tags: c, file, binary, fread

I am trying to read double values from a binary in C, but the binary starts with an integer and then the doubles I am looking for.
How do I skip that first 4 bytes when reading with fread()?
Thanks

Comment: Look at fseek(). But take care regarding the type sizes. An "integer" may not be always 4 bytes, it will depend on the architecture of the machine that created the binary file.

Comment: Thanks. Using sizeof(int) instead of 4 bytes would be OK?

Comment: It may not in a C implementation, but OP said it is 4 bytes in a file.

Comment: If the file was not created in the same machine, then it's also risky to read the doubles as they may not be formatted the same way.

Comment: Is the integer not something useful - like the number of `double` values in the file? Immediately allocating an array of that size will speed the process up no end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
fseek(input, sizeof(int), SEEK_SET);
```

before any calls to `fread`.

As  Weather Vane said you can use `sizeof(int)` safely if the file was generated in the same system architecture as the program you are writing. Otherwise, you should manually specify the size of integer of the system where the file originated.

Comment: That assumes the file was created in the same system. OP said it is 4 bytes. `fseek(input, 4, SEEK_SET);`

Answer (score 1):

You can use fseek to skip the initial integer. If you insist on using fread anyway, then you can read the integer first:

`fread(ptr, sizeof(int), 1, stream)`.

Of course you have to declare `ptr` before calling `fread`.

As I said, `fseek` is another option:

`fseek(stream, sizeof(int), SEEK_SET)`.

Beware that fseek moves the file pointer in bytes (1 in the given line from the beginning of the file); `integer` can be 4 or other number of bytes which is system specific.

Comment: `fread()` does not take an `int *` pointer, it takes `void *`.

Comment: @WeatherVane Indeed. Corrected.

Comment: When a function takes a `void*` pointer, it accepts a pointer to any data type without a cast. Similarly, a function that returns a `void*` pointer type, is intended to be assigned to a typed pointer, without a cast.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful when implementing things like this. If the file isn't created on the same machine, you may get invalid values due to different floating point specifications.

If the file you're reading is created on the same machine, make sure that the program that writes, correctly address the type sizes.

If both writer and reader are developed in C and are supposed to run only on the same machine, use the fseek() with the sizeof(type) used in the writer in the offset parameter.

If the machine that writes the binary isn't the same that will read it, you probably don't want to even read the doubles with fread() as their format may differ due to possible different architectures.

Many architectures rely on the IEEE 754 for floating point format, but if the application is supposed to address multi-platform support, you should make sure that the serialized format can be read from all architectures (or converted while unserializing).

Answer (score -1):

Just read those 4 unneeded bytes, like

```
void* buffer = malloc(sizeof(double));
fread(buffer,4,1,input); //to skip those four bytes

fread(buffer,sizeof(double),1,input); //then read first double =)
double* data = (double*)buffer;//then convert it to double
```

And so on

Comment: `void* buffer = malloc(sizeof(double));` ?? You could have read to for example `double dval` in the first place.